# Node.js Puppeteer - Can't set HTML element inside page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I'm using node.js puppeteer and having trouble with the page.evaluate method. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
    console.log(response); 
    //Valid, prints a regular old string
    await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementById('myelement').innerHTML = response); 
    //Doesn't work, I'm given the error 'response is not defined'
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You have to add response variable as a parameter in lambda and add as parameter in the evaluate function

Comment: @JoelHarkes so like this:  await page.evaluate((response) => document.getElementById('myelement').innerHTML = response);

Comment: And then add it as second parameter of the evaluate function as well. See my response.

Comment: Note: the response variable has to be serializable.

Answer (score 3):

Response variable is not send to the chrome browser, you have to add it as a parameter of the evaluate function.

```
console.log(response); 

await page.evaluate((response) => document.getElementById('myelement').innerHTML = response, response);
```